# Tkinter, Label/Text in canvas.rectangle [python]

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I need to place a text/label centred in a canvas rectangle in tkinter.

First I have a canvas covering the whole screen(800, 600).
And then I have a couple of rectangles which I made using the:

```
create_rectangle(...)
```

The first X of the first rectangle is 275 and the second X is 525.

The first Y of the first rectangle is 265 and the second Y is 315.

```
menuBtn1 = canvas.create_rectangle(275, 165, 525, 215, fill="#C2B6BF")
```

Now how I can place a text/label in the center of this rectangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [create_text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method). As it says in the link in the description of the position parameter:

> By default, the text
>   is centered on this position. You can override this with the anchor
>   option. For example, if the coordinate is the upper left corner, set
>   the anchor to NW.

So this should be what you want:

```
mylabel = canvas.create_text((400, 190), text="Label text")
```

Comment: But what if I want to move both rectangle and text?