# Can I set the label position in the canvas line (tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcFbJ.png)

I want to take time (00:00) in to canvas line (rectangle).
I think i should set position of label to right way,but it not work.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
 
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = Canvas(width=600, height=180, bg='white')   
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)     
root.geometry("605x182")          
root.title("display")    
#root.resizable(False, False)

status = Label(canvas, text='Status : ', fg='white', bg='#213058')
status.pack(anchor="w",padx=3, pady=3)

line = canvas.create_line(3, 0, 3, 90, fill="#213058", width=5)
line = canvas.create_line(3, 3, 600, 3, fill="#213058", width=5)
line = canvas.create_line(600, 0, 600, 90, fill="#213058", width=5)
line = canvas.create_line(2, 90, 600, 90, fill="#213058", width=5)

time = Label(canvas, text='Time : ', fg='white', bg='#213058')
time.pack(anchor="w",padx= 229,pady=61)
line = canvas.create_line(230, 90, 230, 177, fill="#213058", width=5)
line = canvas.create_line(228, 177, 603, 177, fill="#213058", width=5)
line = canvas.create_line(600, 177, 600, 90, fill="#213058", width=5)

showtime = Label(canvas, text='00:00', fg='white', bg='#213058')
showtime.pack(anchor="w",padx= 0,pady=0)

      
mainloop()
```

this is my code.

i don't know how to fix it. please help me.

**thank you very much.**

Comment: Does this help ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087139/tkinter-label-text-in-canvas-rectangle-python

Comment: Or you looking for something like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820520/tkinter-canvas-create-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `create_window` to add the label widget, or use `create_text` add the text without creating an extra label widget. You can then place it wherever you want.